# My phone was stolen and I received a text message asking me to log in to iCloud, but I don't recognize the URL. Is this a scam?

Tags: iphone, icloud, activation-lock

My phone was stolen a few days ago. Now, I just received a SMS message that my phone has been located and that I need to login to my iCloud account to view the current location. However, the page is not on Apple domain or iCloud. Instead, the link is https: //apple-fndmys. us/?id=ODUzMDM=Contacto (without the whitespace)

I'm 99.9% sure this is  a scam and the thieves are trying to get my info as well, but just wondering if this is real for that 0.01% slim chance.

Comment: FYI apple-fndmys.us is being reported by Firefox as a deceptive site.

Comment: Also, I'm curoious where they got your phone number from (and presumably a different number to that on the phone that was stolen).

Comment: @Darren I assume they got it from the SIM

Comment: @Devin, my suspicion is that the criminals are autodialing many numbers for phishing..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably a scam. It would be *weird* for Apple to use a shady link like that.

The golden rules really for any incoming unsolicited phone calls and services is

1. Don't ever give out personal information for an incoming call or direct message.
2. Just find out what the service is, and contact them via their PUBLICLY available details. (That is, go to their public well-known website and get the phone number and call that, and if necessary ask for the person who called you.)

So, adapting this idea. If you're unsure, go on Google, search for iCloud (I'll save you the hassle, it's icloud.com), login there, then go to find-my and see if your phone is showing up anywhere then lock it.

Make sure your phone is registered with 1) Apple* and 2) the police as stolen. The truth is "fences" (folks who launder stolen stuff for thieves) really don't like Apple gear because it phones home if it's registered as stolen, and if it's locked at the OS level it's next to impossible to unlock. That phoning home makes it a borderline radioactive risk for getting sprung by the cops. As a result, really the only way to move iPhones and Macs is to strip them down for parts, and that's a big reason why Apple gets a pass for shanking independent repairers. So there's a decent chance your phone might actually turn up somewhere, although the fact you've gotten this shady link suggests it might already be in the stage of laundering where the fence is working out if it can be unlocked or has to be recycled.

*Oh and by "Register with apple" I mean get on a telephone, call apple and tell them your phone is stolen. If you have some sort of police report number, give that to them too.  They will mark it down as stolen. And the phone will be unlockable until you have it again.

Comment: What do you mean by “make sure your phone is registered with Apple as stolen”? How do you exactly do that?

Comment: Phone them! I think it can be done in the find-my-iphone interface too. But you can totally just call apple. And I suspect the cops would advise you to do just that.

Comment: [Here are the steps](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT201472) Apple recommends that someone whose iPhone or iPad is stolen should take. None of them seems to involve calling Apple or registering the device as stolen with Apple unless the device is covered by AppleCare+ with Theft and Loss.

Comment: Uh its right there in step 2 lol. You *absolutely* can contact apple by phone however. The Applecare+ thing is just about getting a replacement on your warranty.

Comment: That's not contacting or calling Apple. That's marking your phone as lost through the Find My app. If that's what you mean, it would be more helpful if you update your answer.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. Phone apple. Its not complicated. Get on the phone, dial up, tell them. They'll mark it as stolen.

Answer (score 7):

That is an attempt to take over your iCloud account and Apple ID by the person who stole your iPhone, or the person to whom it has been sold.

You probably should change your iCloud password if you get any emails from Apple or any other SMS to be safe.

The address for the link does not appear to belong to a legitimate Apple-related domain and isn’t listed as part of the official support steps for reporting / recovering a stolen phone.

If they succeed in stealing your Apple ID to unlock the phone, you may be locked out forever from your linked Apple accounts.

In addition, it might help taking a look at the [steps Apple recommends](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT201472) be taken  when an iPhone or iPad is stolen as well as the [iCloud security article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201303).

> Never give your Apple ID password, verification codes, device passcode, recovery key, or any account security details to anyone else. Apple will never ask you for this information.

Comment: I’d like to reinforce the sentence **Apple will never ask you for this information.**

Comment: @bmike That's a good reminder but what might be slightly confusing in this case is that it looks like the OP is being asked to enter his Apple ID and password on the linked web site as he would do on a legitimate Apple web site, not verbally provide them.

Comment: Also, on top of the steps, actually phone apple and let them know and if you have a police report number for the theft, give them that, makes it easier to coordinate if the cops find the phone, and if it turns up in a hock-shop it removes all possibility of them denying its your phone.

Answer (score 3):

This is not special nor specific to Apple. When you receive suspiciously URL'd texts or emails **always** Google the expected service first. **Always** do this for every frickin' thing.

Googling "icloud find phone" brings up https://www.icloud.com/find. So log in there and see if anything is reported.

So yes, the text is 99.99995% likely to be a scam.